Find subfolders using a lot of disk space
I'd love to write a bash script that helps me find opportunities for reducing disk usage.
The script would accept 2 arguments: a parent folder (which for me will usually be /apps/), and a threshold (such as "200M").
My current approach is not ideal (doesn't use a threshold and shows a lot of redundant output).
Currently I run cd /apps/ && du -aBM 2>/dev/null | sort -nr | head -n 15 and see output like:
8975M   .
1448M   ./delta
1387M   ./alpha
1350M   ./alpha/releases
1144M   ./bravo/releases
1144M   ./bravo
1137M   ./charlie
1117M   ./delta/releases
902M    ./alpha/releases/202210091311
871M    ./charlie/releases
796M    ./echo
794M    ./echo/releases
791M    ./alpha/releases/202210091311/node_modules
703M    ./scoreboard
684M    ./scoreboard/node_modules

I'd like the output to omit lines like:
8975M   .
1448M   ./delta
1387M   ./alpha
1350M   ./alpha/releases
1144M   ./bravo
1137M   ./charlie
902M    ./alpha/releases/202210091311
796M    ./echo
703M    ./scoreboard

because those were a waste of my attention since the output above had also included subfolders of those folders that were above the threshold that I care about (200M).
These are the more interesting lines:
1144M   ./bravo/releases
1117M   ./delta/releases
871M    ./charlie/releases
794M    ./echo/releases
791M    ./alpha/releases/202210091311/node_modules
684M    ./scoreboard/node_modules

I don't think the du -aBM 2>/dev/null | sort -nr approach is the right starting place to achieve my actual goal, though.
Because in reality, maybe any of those folders (in my most recent example) aren't even as nested / deep as they could be (the lowest level subfolders that also satisfy the threshold of 200 MB).
For example, maybe /echo/subfolder1 and /echo/subfolder2 are each 300M.
I have a cloud server with limited disk space and don't want to pay for more.

796M    ./echo This line is in both the "omit" and "interesting" lists...

It is more worthwhile looking for the top 1% in file sizes in the largest directories and there are tools around to do that. High res video files use up a lot of space. Disk space is now cheap so unless you are actually running out it is no longer worth worrying about. Deleting a few redundant  huge files every now and then is good enough.

@JohnGordon Fixed, thanks.

@MartinBrown I personally don't prefer to spend money on storage of files that I don't need. This is a legit technical question that I'm curious about, and I wish people wouldn't downvote it. I've already looked at storage analysis tools like ncdu which are cool but not convenient enough.

When I compare the list of things you don't like and the list of things you do like, I don't see any difference (there might be one for you, obviously, but I don't see it). As long as you're not capable of making a clear distinction between the things you like to see and the others, how will you explain this to your computer? :-)

@Dominique The 2 lines where I attempted to describe the distinction were: because those were a waste of my attention since the output above had also included subfolders of those folders that were above the threshold that I care about and in reality, maybe any of those folders (in my most recent example) aren't even as nested / deep as they could be (the lowest level subfolders that also satisfy the threshold of 200 MB). I could try to write it out even clearer, but I tried to be succinct since the StackOverflow community favors brevity even at the expense of clarity, unfortunately.

Directory hierarchy is a tree. Its nodes are directories and files. For files, value of node is its size. For directories, value of node is sum of sizes of all its children. I believe the problem given is to select nodes with value larger than some threshold whose children are all smaller than that threshold.
It is already known how to select the 15 largest of these.

Conveniently, du -a automatically provides a postordering of a depth-first search of the tree.
So a solution to the problem is to walk du's output.

if path has been "seen", do nothing
else, if size exceeds threshold:

print the line
mark all ancestor paths as seen



This works because the postordering means an unmarked path that exceeds the threshold cannot have smaller children.
Assuming that paths don't start with whitespace nor contain newlines:
du -aBM /apps/ 2>/dev/null |
awk -F/ -v OFS=/ -v min=200 '
    $1+0 > min {
        raw = $0
        sub(/^[0-9]+M[ \t]+/,"") # strip size
        sub(/\/+$/,"") # strip trailing slashes

        if ($0 in seen) next

        print raw

        # mark ancestors as seen
        s = $1
        for (f=1; f<NF; s = s OFS $(++f))
            seen[s]
    }
' |
sort -rn | head -15


The du -S answer usefully solves a slightly-different related problem, where value of directory nodes is sum of sizes of children that are files, and only directory nodes are selected.
You can also turn it into a function
Create a bash alias like:
function du_top() {
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/78716652/470749
    local path=$1
    local min_size=$2
    local num_results=$3
    du -aBM "$path" 2>/dev/null | \
    awk -F/ -v OFS=/ -v min="$min_size" '
        $1+0 > min {
            raw = $0
            sub(/^[0-9]+M[ \t]+/,"") # strip size
            sub(/\/+$/,"") # strip trailing slashes

            if ($0 in seen) next

            print raw

            # mark ancestors as seen
            s = $1
            for (f=1; f<NF; s = s OFS $(++f))
                seen[s]
        }
    ' | \
    sort -rn | head -n "$num_results"
}

After sourcing it, then run it like du_top /apps/ 200 15.

This looks great and seems like it might be correct! Thank you! P.S. It would be even better to sort the final output by size descending. I can probably figure out how to do that.

It looks as if the du -S option is exactly what you're looking for:
$ du --help
...
  -S, --separate-dirs   for directories do not include size of subdirectories
...

$ du -SBM | sort -nr | head -n 15

The above command should give you a list of the 15 largest directories, not counting subdirectories. Adjust the head -n number until you get to your desired threshold.
(Note also that I've omitted the du -a option as you don't want to see sizes of individual files mixed in with directory sizes, as that would give you duplicate information.)

Interesting alternative approach. It won't coalesce small branches and show them when the total passes the threshold, but that may not be a problem.

This looks interesting. Really simple command. Although I don't understand that line from the  help docs. I just tested it and don't think it quite achieves what I was asking for, but it's easier to remember and useful in a pinch because it does help me find some large folders. Thanks.

@Ryan what that line from the help docs means is, for example if a directory contains files that total 100MB, and also contains a subdirectory that in turn contains 50MB of files, then the -S option will show the size of the directory as 100MB, because it excludes the subdirectory. Without the -S option it will show 150MB because by default it includes subdirectories.

Oh, now I understand. Thanks!!

Here's a start at least (no time to polish it right now to to get rid of "./charlie" and convert file sizes to bytes for final comparison):
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sort -k2 "${@:--}" |
awk '
    {
        dir = $0
        sub(/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"",dir)
    }
    index(dir,prev"/") == 1 {
        delete dirs[prev]
    }
    {
        dirs[dir] = $0
        prev = dir
    }
    END {
        for ( dir in dirs ) {
            print dirs[dir]
        }
    }
' |
sort -rn


$ cat file | ./tst.sh
1350M   ./alpha/releases
1144M   ./bravo/releases
1137M   ./charlie
1117M   ./delta/releases
871M    ./charlie/releases
794M    ./echo/releases
791M    ./alpha/releases/202210091311/node_modules
684M    ./scoreboard/node_modules

Replace cat file with the du command from the question.

The first line of your output is alpha/releases which the OP specified as not wanted. This is because it contains 1350M while one of its subdirectories contains 791M, so the most it could contain in plain files is (1350-791) = 559M which is not much.

@k314159 as I mentioned in my answer "here is a start...". It shows the typical approach for problems like this one of sorting by path first, discarding parent directories, then sorting by size.
